# Unit testing: How can i import test classes dynamically and run?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I'm doing a simple script to run and test my code. How can i import dinamically and run my test classes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're *asking* here.  If you've got a solution, then you can answer it yourself by posting it first as a question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. Can you clarify? What are the expected results? What are you seeing?

Comment: Sorry @AIG. I hope I have clarified the idea.

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is too simple and perform what i want.

```
import unittest

def execute_all_tests(tests_folder):
    suites = unittest.TestLoader().discover(tests_folder)
    text_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suites)
```

Comment: Note to community - the incorrect answer is upvoted, here. Yes, it's the close second, but it's not DRY, bc all these Python auto-test rigs have automated runners. Only use this code if you need to screw with the default runner's highest-level behaviors; I can't think of a reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that I found to import and dynamically run my test classes.

```
import glob
import os
import imp
import unittest

def execute_all_tests(tests_folder):
    test_file_strings = glob.glob(os.path.join(tests_folder, 'test_*.py'))
    suites = []
    for test in test_file_strings:
        mod_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(test)[-1])
        py_mod = imp.load_source(mod_name, test)
        suites.append(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromModule(py_mod))
    text_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(unittest.TestSuite(suites))
```

Comment: You don't need to do this as it is reinventing what is already available.

Answer (score 0):

Install `pytest`, and run your tests with a command like:

```
py.test src
```

That's it. Py.test will load all `test_*.py` files, find all `def test_*` calls inside them, and run each one for you.

The board is having trouble answering your question because it's in "why is water wet?" territory; all test rigs come with runners that automatically do what your code snip does, so you only need read the tutorial for one to get started.

And *major* props for writing auto tests at all; they put you above 75% of all programmers.